# How can i create uitextfield in uitableview and can be add and edit textfield and save to SQLite

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

How can i create uitextfield in uitableview and can be add and edit textfield and save to SQLite.

[image]

I try to create uitextfield into tabelviewcell, user insert row when click button “plus” but i don’t know how to input text into uitextfiled and save to array to SQLite.

Please advise me. Thank you

Comment: First step should always be searching...

Comment: @DonMag I found solution to save label in SQLite but i don't 
understand about textfield.text save to SQLite.

Comment: Think a bit more about what you want to ask... You say you can save a *"label"* in SQLite? If so, what do you think the difference would be between `label.text` and `textField.text`?

Comment: @DonMag Thank you from your advice. Now i found solution. I use delegate textfield to save in arrayText[index.row] and then when click save. i use arrayText save to SQLite.